# how to see complete value of CLOB variable in TOAD while debugging

Tags: database, oracle, toad, clob

In Packages , how can I see complete value of clob variable in debug mode on toad. Currently if I click on add watch on clob varibale and go to modify it shows  only "open=F, temp=T, length=354, chunksize=8132, data=

Comment: hi Darshan, I'm not sure if this is what you are searching for, but you can try: 1. Go to View | Toad Options
2. Expand Data Grids | Data
3. On the right-hand side, check 'Preview CLOB and LONG data'
4. Click on OK and refresh your Schema Browser

Comment: I didn't use DEBUG mode before, but the way above is how I check CLOB variable normally

Answer (score 3):

Try watching `to_char(your_clob_var)`

---

**EDIT :**
Unfortunately, TOAD seems to accept only variables to be watched or inspected.
You can't watch expression like `n+1` or `to_char(clob_var)`.
But when watching clob you see full information about it including its text:

```
Scope   Owner       Name            Expression Value    
Local   SCHEMA_NAME PROCEDURE_NAME  clob_var   open=F, temp=T, length=7, chunksize=16324, data=String_inside_this_clob
```

`open=F, temp=T, length=354, chunksize=8132, data=` means text starts with `LF` char :-) .  Go to menu `Debug -> Evaluate/Modify (Ctrl+Alt+E)` to view full text.

Comment: ok. Thanks . Is there a concept of immediate window in toad (like we have in Visual studio), where I can fire to_char(your_clob_var) and see value. or do I need to modify script and write this to DBMS Output ?  (sorry askg basic question my first encounter with Toad :()